# Integral remainder from Taylor's formula

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

The [wikipedia version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder) of the integral remainder from Taylor's theorem says (if I want an order 2 expansion)$$f(y)=f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+{1\over2}f''(x)(y-x)^2+{1\over2}\int\limits_x^y(y-z)^2f'''(z)dz$$

But in a proof that I am reading, I have a different expression for the remainder that I am struggling to derive by myself:

$$f(y)=f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+{1\over2}f''(x)(y-x)^2+\int\limits_x^y(y-z)(f''(z)-f''(x))dz$$

That's basically my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration by parts with $g(z) = - \frac 12 (y-z)^2$ and $h(z) = f''(z)-f''(x)$:
$$
\int_x^y (y-z)(f''(z)-f''(x)) \, dz = \int_x^y g'(z)h(z) \, dz \\
= \underbrace{g(y)}_{= 0}h(y) - g(x)\underbrace{ h(x)}_{= 0} - \int_x^y g(z)h'(z) \, dz 
= \frac 12 \int_x^y (y-z)^2 f'''(z) \, dz \, .
$$